# How to put bathroom exhaust fan and light on separate switch using two 12/2 cables?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, exhaust-fan

**The Situation:**

I have a bathroom exhaust fan / light combination unit. At the top of the unit there are five wires coming out:

- One black and one white wire for the fan
- One black and one white wire for the light
- One green wire for the ground

So, the fan and light have separate neutral wires.

The exhaust fan and light will be on separate switches.

I have some 12/2 wire from previous projects and would like to use this rather than buying new 12/3 if possible.

**The Question:**

Can I use two 12/2 cables?

One cable would go from the fan switch to the fan, tying black wire to the black fan wire and white wire to the white fan wire.  The other cable would go from the light switch to the light, tying the black wire to the black light wire and the white wire to the white light wire. Lastly, the ground from each cable would be tied together to the ground wire on the fan/light unit.

Seems possible, but I have read that I need to use a 12/3 cable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly fine. As long as you match the hots and neutrals in a cable, you are good.